# How to install pyodbc to be used in ipython

Tags: python, installation, ipython, pyodbc

I'm confused. I have installed pyodbc on my computer and I was able to import it using other IDE 
but i'm new to ipython.

I use Ananconda , and was able to install other library using something like

```
pip install BeautifulSoup
```

But when I do that with pyodbc  using

```
pip install pyodbc
```

I got error :

```
error: command 'gcc' failed with exist status 1
```

---

C:\Users\jeannie.chirayu>pip install pyodbc
Downloading/unpacking pyodbc
  You are installing a potentially insecure and unverifiable file. Future versio
ns of pip will default to disallowing insecure files.
  Downloading pyodbc-3.0.7.zip (85kB): 85kB downloaded
  Running setup.py egg_info for package pyodbc

```
warning: no files found matching 'tests\*'
```

Installing collected packages: pyodbc
  Running setup.py install for pyodbc
    building 'pyodbc' extension
    C:\Anaconda\Scripts\gcc.bat -DMS_WIN64 -mdll -O -Wall -DPYODBC_VERSION=3.0.7
 -IC:\Anaconda\include -IC:\Anaconda\PC -c c:\users\jeanni~1.chi\appdata\local\t
emp\pip_build_jeannie.chirayu\pyodbc\src\buffer.cpp -o c:\users\jeanni~1.chi\app
data\local\temp\pip_build_jeannie.chirayu\pyodbc\src\buffer.o /Wall /wd4668 /wd4
820 /wd4711 /wd4100 /wd4127 /wd4191
    gcc.exe: error: /Wall: No such file or directory
    gcc.exe: error: /wd4668: No such file or directory
    gcc.exe: error: /wd4820: No such file or directory
    gcc.exe: error: /wd4711: No such file or directory
    gcc.exe: error: /wd4100: No such file or directory
    gcc.exe: error: /wd4127: No such file or directory
    gcc.exe: error: /wd4191: No such file or directory
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
    Complete output from command C:\Anaconda\python.exe -c "import setuptools;__
file__='c:\users\jeanni~1.chi\appdata\local\temp\pip_build_jeannie.chirayu
\pyodbc\setup.py';exec(compile(open(**file**).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __
file__, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\jeanni~1.chi\appdata\local\temp\pip-
lqnyba-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed:
    running install

running build

running build_ext

building 'pyodbc' extension

C:\Anaconda\Scripts\gcc.bat -DMS_WIN64 -mdll -O -Wall -DPYODBC_VERSION=3.0.7 -IC
:\Anaconda\include -IC:\Anaconda\PC -c c:\users\jeanni~1.chi\appdata\local\temp\
pip_build_jeannie.chirayu\pyodbc\src\buffer.cpp -o c:\users\jeanni~1.chi\appdata
\local\temp\pip_build_jeannie.chirayu\pyodbc\src\buffer.o /Wall /wd4668 /wd4820
/wd4711 /wd4100 /wd4127 /wd4191

gcc.exe: error: /Wall: No such file or directory

gcc.exe: error: /wd4668: No such file or directory

gcc.exe: error: /wd4820: No such file or directory

gcc.exe: error: /wd4711: No such file or directory

gcc.exe: error: /wd4100: No such file or directory

gcc.exe: error: /wd4127: No such file or directory

gcc.exe: error: /wd4191: No such file or directory

error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

---

Cleaning up...
Command C:\Anaconda\python.exe -c "import setuptools;**file**='c:\users\jeanni
~1.chi\appdata\local\temp\pip_build_jeannie.chirayu\pyodbc\setup.py';exec(
compile(open(**file**).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), **file**, 'exec'))" install
 --record c:\users\jeanni~1.chi\appdata\local\temp\pip-lqnyba-record\install-rec
ord.txt --single-version-externally-managed failed with error code 1 in c:\users
\jeanni~1.chi\appdata\local\temp\pip_build_jeannie.chirayu\pyodbc
Storing complete log in C:\Users\j\pip\pip.log

Any recommendation would help. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this was annoying. but i got it working. basically, pyodbc source code is missing a lot of crap.

1) in the pyodbc directory, open setup.py and search for "wd4668".

change that list to look like this:

```
settings['extra_compile_args'] = []
```

2) in the src directory, create a file called "abc_minmax.h". in it, put:

```
#ifndef min 

#define min(a, b) ((a < b) ? a : b)
#define max(a, b) ((a > b) ? a : b)

#endif
```

3) in the following files in the src directory:

```
cursor.h
params.h
sqlwchar.h
```

add the following line near the other includes at the top:

```
#include "abc_minmax.h"
```

4) finally, in the file wrapper.h, add the following 2 lines near the other includes:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <Winreg.h>
```

ok, that should do it! let me know if something doesn't work.

Comment: I tried this but i get this: ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-dbc27c5f2947> in <module>()
----> 1 import pyodbc

ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.

Answer (score 0):

It won't help with the pip install issues but you could download the .exes from https://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/ 
or
http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/