# How to connect to a SQL Server database in Anaconda

Tags: python, sql-server, odbc, anaconda

I'm quite new to Python and programming in general, so please bear with me. At my work I have Anaconda (Python vers 2.7) installed and would like to connect to a Microsoft SQL Server database, preferably with ODBC. Related to this task I have a number of questions:

- Is it correct that I cannot connect to a SQL Server database using sqlite3 or sqlalchemy? That I need a module like pyodbc? A brief explanation of why this is the case would be much appreciated.
- EDIT: Question related to installation of pyodbc in anaconda removed, since I figured this out (by reading [Cannot Install Python Modules after Installing Anaconda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18840292/cannot-install-python-modules-after-installing-anaconda?rq=1))

Help is much appreciated! If any of my questions/any other specifics need to be cleared up, please don't hesitate to ask. Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I do not use Anaconda, but I use various databases and ODBC. At first you can try if you have `odbc` module installed. It is a part of `pywin32` package (http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/) and is packed with ActiveState Python distribution. Other distribution can install it separately. Simply try:

```
import odbc
db = odbc.odbc('dsn/user/password')
```

You can also try with `pyodbc` you mentioned in question. There is precompiled version for Windows and I think it will work with your Anaconda environment. After installing try:

```
import pyodbc
db = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server Native Client 10.0};Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Uid=myUsername;Pwd=myPassword;')
```

You can find more connection strings at http://www.connectionstrings.com/

**EDIT:**

It seems that you have problem with *bitness* of ODBC driver.

Try to run this program to see what sources are visible to ODBC manager:

```
import odbc

source =  odbc.SQLDataSources(odbc.SQL_FETCH_FIRST)
while source:
    print(source)
    source =  odbc.SQLDataSources(odbc.SQL_FETCH_NEXT)
```

Comment: Thanks for your input! Pywin32 is part of the Anaconda package, so I will try connecting with the odbc module, when i'm at work monday. I have an additional question: I have a dsn and username for the sql server I'm trying to connect to, is it possible that a password is not needed? If so, how can I represent this in the connection string you suggested, *odbc.odbc('dsn/user/password')*?

Comment: Leave password empty with: `db = odbc.odbc('DSN/user/')` . For MS Access `DSN=northwind` I can use: `db = odbc.odbc('northwind//')` or `db = odbc.odbc('northwind')`

Comment: I don't know what you plan to do with database, but `pydobc` is more advanced than `odbc`. For example `pyodbc` fills `description` field in recordset returned by SELECT.

Comment: Ok great. I pretty much just need to copy some tables from the database. I will try this on monday and report back on whether it works!

Comment: When i try: `import odbc db=odbc.odbc('DSN')` i get following error message: Traceback (most recent call last): _italic_File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module> dbi.internalError: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] The given DSN contains a misalignment between the architechture of the driver and the program in LOGIN._italic_ I've translated the last sentence in the error message from danish...

Comment: In 64 bit systems there are two odbcad32: one for 32 bit applications (c:\windows\syswow64) and one for 64 bit applications (c:\windows\system32). Make sure your DSN is visible for architecture in which your Anaconda works. For example after I start Python I see `Python 2.7.2 ... [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]` which means I can work with DSN described by `c:\windows\syswow64\odbcad32.exe` (32 bit version)

Comment: The server I am trying to connect to is 32-bit. When I open Anaconda, it says `Python 2.7.5...[MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]`. I guess this is where the problem lies - ODBC depends on same bitness? Do you have any suggestion on how to solve this problem?

Comment: As in my last comment there are 2 ODBC managers: `odbcad32.exe`. ODBC depends from native drivers that differs in "bitness". Do you have DSN defined in 64 bit version of `odbcad32.exe`? Can you test connection from it?

Comment: Hi Michal. Sorry I don't quite understand your suggestion/question. Are you asking whether I have a 64-bit DSN for the database I am trying to connect to? I guess I am a little confused, since I thought that a database either could be 32-bit or 64-bit, and if it is 32-bit (as is the case currently) then getting a 64-bit DSN is not a possibility. I should mention that I don't have "control" over the database ie. I can't change the bitness of the database. Thanks very much for your great help so far!

Comment: Not "bitness" of database, but "bitness" of ODBC drivers. You use 64 bit version of Python, so you need 64 bit version of ODBC driver and DSN that is defined by 64 bit version of `odbcad32.exe`. Database can be on 32 bit system, but drivers must be 64 bit.

Comment: I added simple code to check what sources (DSN) are visible to ODBC manager.

Comment: Hi Michal. I ran the code you provided and got:   ('dBASE Files', 'Microsoft Access dBASE Driver (*.dbf, *.ndx, *.mdx)')
('Excel Files', 'Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls, *.xlsx, *.xlsm, *.xlsb)')
('MS Access Database', 'Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)')

Comment: Hi again. I finally understand your point! I'm now working on having a 64-bit DSN created for the database. Thank you so much for your help!