# Python error: 'gcc' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: python, gcc, anaconda

I'm trying to apply the [Zhang-Suen thinning algorithm](https://github.com/bsdnoobz/zhang-suen-thinning/blob/master/thinning.py) for a fingerprint recognition system. But I get this error :

```
'gcc' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "newff.py", line 69, in <module>
    sk = thinning(bn);
  File "newff.py", line 47, in thinning
    dst = _thinningIteration(dst, 0)
  File "newff.py", line 37, in _thinningIteration
    weave.inline(expr, ["I", "iter", "M"])
  File "E:\Anaconda2\Lib\site-packages\scipy\weave\inline_tools.py", line 366, i
n inline
    **kw)
  File "E:\Anaconda2\Lib\site-packages\scipy\weave\inline_tools.py", line 496, i
n compile_function
    verbose=verbose, **kw)
  File "E:\Anaconda2\Lib\site-packages\scipy\weave\ext_tools.py", line 373, in c
ompile
    verbose=verbose, **kw)
  File "E:\Anaconda2\Lib\site-packages\scipy\weave\build_tools.py", line 279, in
 build_extension
    setup(name=module_name, ext_modules=[ext],verbose=verb)
  File "E:\Anaconda2\Lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\core.py", line 169, in se
tup
    return old_setup(**new_attr)
  File "c:\Python27\lib\distutils\core.py", line 159, in setup
    raise SystemExit, "error: %s" % (exc,)
distutils.errors.CompileError: error: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file
specified
```

I searched everywhere but I didn't find the same problem posted ever before.

Comment: if you are on linux you just install gcc from the package manager. If you are windows its a different story. I just say the C: in the stack trace. search on how to install gcc on windows. http://preshing.com/20141108/how-to-install-the-latest-gcc-on-windows/

Comment: just found this which might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18840292/cannot-install-python-modules-after-installing-anaconda

Comment: @Lynch I installed it but It didn't work. How could python from c:\python27 use gcc from c:\cygwin ?

Comment: My firts link was a mistake. I think the second one is better. But you definitively need to install gcc on your machine. I dont have windows so I cant test, this is why I write comments instead of answers. The second link suggest `conda install mingw`, it so simple to test I think its worth a try.

Comment: Okay, I just installed mingw, now the first two lines of the error are gone (gcc). But I still get the other error of scipy weave!

Comment: The error message says the system cannot find the specified file. try debugging it and find what file is missing. Learn about ipdb if you dont have an IDE that help you set breakpoints.